# как исправить нахождение инициалов И. О. по полным фамилии, имени, отчеству

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

```
a = 'Буйносов Иван Пиванович', 'Иванов Р.О.', 'Маслова Г. А.'

b = [u'{} {}. {}.'.format(x[:x.find(' ')], x[x.find(' ') + 1], x[x.rfind(' ') + 1]) for x in a]
```

Когда вывожу на печать:

```
['Буйносов И. П.', 'Иванов Р. Р.', 'Маслова Г. А.']
```

Не `Иванов Р. О.`, а `Иванов Р. Р.` получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

я бы использовал регулярки для подобного рода задач:

```
import re

In [105]: a
Out[105]: ('Буйносов Иван Пиванович', 'Иванов Р.О.', 'Маслова Г. А.')

In [106]: [re.sub(r'(\w+)\s+(\w)\w{2,}\s+(\w)\w{2,}', r'\1 \2. \3.', x) for x in a]
Out[106]: ['Буйносов И. П.', 'Иванов Р.О.', 'Маслова Г. А.']
```

Уточненная регулярка, которая нормализует инициалы, добавляя пробел: `Р.О.` -> `Р. О.`:

```
In [125]: [re.sub(r'(\w+)\s+(\w)(?:\.\s*?|\w{1,})\s*?(\w)(?:\.|\w{1,})', r'\1 \2. \3.', x) for x in a]
Out[125]: ['Буйносов И. П.', 'Иванов Р. О.', 'Маслова Г. А.']
```